# React Render DOM elements if two props have same string value

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I have two props.
One have this data:

```html
[
        {
            "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf",
            "name": "Restaurant0",
            "location": "Tokio",
            "workinghours": 18,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c6468dd7982450218a95ad0",
            "name": "Restaurant1",
            "location": "Tokio",
            "workinghours": 24,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c6468ea7982450218a95ad1",
            "name": "Restaurant3",
            "location": "Tokio",
            "workinghours": 15,
            "__v": 0
        },
    ]
```

Other one looks like this:

```html
   [
    {
        "_id": "5c73fe32bee55c27a4d62e34",
        "user": "asa",
        "restaurantName": "Restaurant0",
        "foodName": "Apple Pie",
        "orderDate": "25.02.2019.",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c73fe82bee55c27a4d62e35",
        "user": "asa",
        "restaurantName": "Restaurant1",
        "foodName": "Apple butter",
        "orderDate": "25.02.2019.",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c73fedebee55c27a4d62e36",
        "user": "asa",
        "restaurantName": "Restaurant2",
        "foodName": "Fried fish",
        "orderDate": "25.02.2019.",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

So my question is how can I display only restaurants that have ordered foods from another json array? I mean, I need data from first array and second array, filtered by restaurant names. So link for that two array needs to be a restaurant name string, to be displayed only specific data. I need this for my React project.

Comment: Just add an example of result you need

Comment: Can I somehow get array to look like this: [ { "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf", "name": "Restaurant0", "location": "Tokio", "workinghours": 18, "user": "asa", "foodName": "Apple Pie", "orderDate": "25.02.2019.", "__v": 0 },]

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Lsqfu26c/

Comment: Check this instead https://jsfiddle.net/Lsqfu26c/2/

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you can merge the two arrays into one then filter it.
Here's code for this:

```
const mergedArray = [...props1, ...props2];
mergedArray.filter(({restaurant}) => restaurant==='specific restaurant');
```

Comment: Please If You can read my new comments for other person here. Thanks for Your answer